# use highchart as a template with different title and different values multiple times

Tags: javascript, python, django, highcharts

Hi i am using highchart to display a simple pie chart. Below follows my javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Infoblox Project Resources'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Project share',
        data: [
            ['Bill',  {{ project }}],
            ['Non-Bill', {{ not_bill }}],

        ]
    }]
};
$('#dashboard').highcharts(options);
$('#dashboard1').highcharts(options);
});
    </script>
```

Here if i want to repeat this chart multiple times. How can i implement it. right now i use every thing as standard in highchart. Except {{ project }} and {{ no_bill }} . This both are integer values which will be rendered by python from django pinax.

Here i want to irate the chart n number of times with different title and different values of {{ project }} and {{ no_bill }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting all options (except data and title) in `Highcharts.setOptions(options)`, just like here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic/dark-unica

Then create charts:

```
$('#dashboard').highcharts({
  title: { text: {{ mytext }} },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Project share',
    data: [
      ['Bill',  {{ project }}],
      ['Non-Bill', {{ not_bill }}],
    ]
  }]
});
$('#dashboard1').highcharts({
  title: { text: {{ mytext_2 }} },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Project share',
    data: [
      ['Bill',  {{ project_2 }}],
      ['Non-Bill', {{ not_bill_2 }}],
    ]
  }]
});
```

Or even better:

```
function createChart(container, text, valA, valB) {
  $(container).highcharts({
    title: { text: text },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Project share',
      data: [
        ['Bill',   valA ],
        ['Non-Bill', valB ],
      ]
    }]
  });
}

createChart('#dashboard', {{ mytext }}, {{ project }}, {{ not_bill }});
createChart('#dashboard1', {{ mytext_2 }}, {{ project_2 }}, {{ not_bill_2 }});
```